# bigQuery - rank/group/another_function events with a value within the same buffer together

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have an sql problem that I think requires windows functions but I am not sure.

Basically i have a table that is similar to this

```
NonUniqueID | Value
    1          35
    1          36
    1          34
    1          60
    2          15
    3          102
    3          150
```

and I would like to identify the events that have the same ID and have a value that is +-5 from each other. So something like this below

```
NonUniqueID | Value | Group
    1          35      A
    1          36      A
    1          34      A
    1          60      B
    2          15      A
    3          102     A
    3          150     B
```

Now I understand that there are a lot of potential hedge cases...but let's now assume that the events are either within +-5 from each other or they are VERT far apart.

I *think* I need to use a window function but I am not sure how I should use it. Ideas?

Comment: what if `Value` column has values from 1 up to 20 consecutively, for example ?

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant for edge cases...let's assume right now that they are either within a small buffer between each other like (-1,3,2,1) and should be in the same Group or very far apart (1,40) and should be in different groups...so we don't need to worry about the situation where you have consecutive values

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that there is a huge gap between each group, you might consider below approach.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT * EXCEPT(offset)
    FROM UNNEST([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3]) NonUniqueID WITH offset
    JOIN UNNEST([35, 26, 34, 60, 15, 102, 150]) Value WITH offset
   USING (offset)
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(flag), CHR(65 + COUNTIF(flag) OVER w1) AS `Group` FROM (
  SELECT *, Value - LAG(Value) OVER w0 >= 10 AS flag
    FROM sample_table
  WINDOW w0 AS (PARTITION BY NonUniqueID ORDER BY Value)
) WINDOW w1 AS (PARTITION BY NonUniqueID ORDER BY Value);
```

**Query results**

[image]

Another example is:

```
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 1 NonUniqueID, Value FROM UNNEST([1, 2, 3, 23, 24, 32, 50, 51, 53]) Value
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(flag), CHR(65 + COUNTIF(flag) OVER w1) AS `Group` FROM (
  SELECT *, Value - LAG(Value) OVER w0 >= 10 AS flag
    FROM sample_table
  WINDOW w0 AS (PARTITION BY NonUniqueID ORDER BY Value)
) WINDOW w1 AS (PARTITION BY NonUniqueID ORDER BY Value);
```

[image]

Comment: mmmm wait, I might be misunderstanding your solution but I don't know what are the values...what do you mean when you write `UNNEST([1, 2, 3, 23, 24, 32, 50, 51, 53])`?

Comment: @giaggi, Just wanted to test the query with another example with more groups.  Here (3, 23) and (32, 50) has a gap more than 10, new group starts from `23` and `50` respectively, if I understood your intention correctly.